# DJI OSDK - how to stream to remote server

Tags: dji-sdk

Could anybody give me tip how to stream from main aircraft camera to remote server? We have our own app runing on RASPI 4 build on Matrice and can get live view from camera, can download h264 file to SD card, but havent't found any description/sample how to stream outside.

Is it possibe to use aircraft-RemoteController connection and then RemoteController to WiFi? Or rather  use RASPI WiFi (that will cut range I assume).

Answer (score 0):

Setup a RTMP server.
Stream to a RTMP-server from the MSDK (which running on the remote).

See the MSDK example project.

Anyway if you search for the class "LiveStreamManager" in the msdk example app on github.

method getLiveStreamManager

```
LiveStreamManager getLiveStreamManager()
```

Provides access to getLiveStreamManager. It can be used to stream the video to a RTMP server to do live streaming with DJI products.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so as shown in the figure below. The RTMP streaming is done by using FFMEPG we stream the section of the desktop to a webRTC server. We use opencv to control the XT2 image box on the desktop and then perform the live streaming. But the normal 4G based point-to-point connection may have 30sec latency, we use a webRTC video server to make the stream realtime.

[image]